# Building a surface from a 2D image based on brightness at each point

Tags: geometry, reference-request, graphing-functions, surfaces, visualization

I want to make a surface based on the brightness at each point of this image. What is the mathematics behind this? I am thinking I need to create a function that takes in the brightness of each pixel and plots it at a height above the point, where brighter corresponds to higher and darker corresponds to lower.

Are there any applications of this?

[image]

Comment: An important keyword is "smoothing". You have to smooth your data in order to have a kind of continuity instead of peaks. You can smooth it by using a filter, say $5 \times 5$ for example, replacing the initial value by the mean of it and its 24 neighbours, or, better by weighting more the grey level of the initial value and its immediate neighbours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much mathematics beyond what you already know: you need a function of two variables (pixel position) whose value at each point is the brightness there. You can build that by parsing the image in some way.

The image seems to be quite dark with some small white spots, which will make a very spiky surface.

There are many tools that will draw a surface for you. Search [3D graphing software](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=3d%20graphing%20software&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). You could even consider Excel, or some programming language like Python.

Comment: okay thanks ethan

Answer (score 0):

3d Builder is pretty good. I made some neat plots with it:

[image]

[image]